# Sandbox Login Issue

Tags: sandbox, org

I have created a new sandbox from production in my org. The sandbox is ready and when I am trying to login using test.salesforce.com, it says that it has sent a verification to the email address but that email address has *********.com.invalid at the end and I did not get any email with verification code.

Can you please help me why this happens and please provide me a solution for login issue into my SandBox.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you refreshed the sandbox, your email wouldn't contain the suffix. If not, then you need to ask the admin who refreshed the sandbox to reset your email.

Comment: It is not refreshed, it is created very newly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from help documentation for [Create a Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&type=5):

> When your sandbox is ready for use, you receive a notification email that your sandbox has completed copying.
>
> To access your sandbox, click the link in the notification email. Users can log in to the sandbox at https://test.salesforce.com by appending `.sandbox_name` to their Salesforce usernames. For example, if a username for a production org is `user1@acme.com`, and the sandbox is named `test` the modified username to log in to the sandbox is `user1@acme.com.test`.
>
> **Salesforce automatically changes sandbox usernames, but not passwords.**

If you created the sandbox, then you should have received that email. If not, then check with the administrator who created the sandbox to reset your email in the new sandbox.